# How to detect if numpy is installed

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing Python code. I want to check if numpy and wxpython are installed on machine. How to do that??

Comment: if the question is answered, please tag one of the answers as such

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can try importing them and then handle the ImportError if the module doesn't exist.

```
try:
    import numpy
except ImportError:
    print "numpy is not installed"
```

Answer (score 44):

I think you also may use this

```
>> import numpy
>> print numpy.__version__
```

**Update**:
for python3
use `print(numpy.__version__)`

Comment: why is this is not a good answer??!! it's the best for me. if it's not installed he won't get the write version

Answer (score 19):

The traditional method for checking for packages in Python is "it's better to beg forgiveness than ask permission", or rather, "it's better to catch an exception than test a condition."

```
try:
    import numpy
    HAS_NUMPY = True
except ImportError:
    HAS_NUMPY = False
```

Answer (score 14):

In the numpy README.txt file, it says

> After installation, tests can be run with:
>
> python -c 'import numpy; numpy.test()'

This should be a sufficient test for proper installation.

Comment: this worked for me. However I checked on another computer, I needed to change the single quotes `'` into double quotes `"`. Not sure what's the reason. Both are windows. The one that needed the double quote uses Anaconda.

Comment: To run `numpy.test()` you will need to have `hypothesis` installed. So `pip install hypothesis` may be needed at some point.

Answer (score 3):

If you use eclipse, you simply type "import numpy" and eclipse will "complain" if doesn't find.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Use following command in python ide.:

```
import numpy
```

**Option 2:**

Go to *Python* -> *site-packages* folder. There you should be able to find numpy and the numpy distribution info folder.

If any of the above is true then you installed numpy successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some methods, which did not work for me.  The simplest way I found was to try to build a numpy array and then print it (see code below).  If the array prints, numpy is installed, if array doesn't print, numpy is not installed.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1. ,2. ,3.], [4. ,5. ,6.]])
print(a)
```