# email program in python

Tags: python, email

My task is to check disk usage on Windows machine and send email to customer when usage is too high. I do have a python script that checks the disk usage but I have an issue to get email script. In my case it should just simple message. I'm not sure if the server where I'll check the space has smtp server but likely I could use it from another system.
My problem is ( I took a script from this site ) - script failed to execute. Here'e the script:
    import smtplib
    import mime
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText

```
fp = open(textfile, 'rb')
# Create a text/plain message
msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
fp.close()

# Format headers
msg['Subject'] = 'My subject'
msg['From'] = 'from@from.fr'
msg['To'] = 'to@to.com'

# Send the message via Michelin SMTP server, but don't include the envelope header.
s = smtplib.SMTP('your mail server')
s.sendmail('from@from.fr', ['to@to.com'], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

And it failed with this error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "email.py", line 1, in 
        import smtplib
      File "c:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 46, in 
        import email.utils
      File "N:\Scripts\email.py", line 2, in 
        import mime
    ImportError: No module named mime

Could someone advice please?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you have this statement: `import mime`? It is not needed and should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included these files.

```
import  smtplib
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
```

Comment: Sure I did. 
This is the beginning of my program:
N:\>type Scripts\email.py
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

fp = open(textfile, 'rb')

Comment: And this is the error:
N:\>python Scripts\email.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Scripts\email.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\ipython\ipython\Lib\smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "N:\Scripts\email.py", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mime

Comment: Well ... I checked both your reference and found interisting thing.
If I execute exactly the same statement I mentioned before in python interective shell I don't see any error. In case I execute it in a script I see the error. What could  be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove `import mime`.

Here's a minimal smtp example that works in Python 2.7 and 3.4:

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

body = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx\r\nyyyyyyy"
#text = "Subject: missing newline\r\n\r\n" + body
text = MIMEText(body).as_string()

s = smtplib.SMTP('exchange.company')
s.sendmail('', 'cees@company', text)
s.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown correct import statements. To import use Mimetext use `from email.mime.text import MIMEText`. Check [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) for more info.

Comment: sorry ... I didn't get what I did wrong ... this is what I used:

from email.mime.text import MIMEText

what is wrong with that statement?

Comment: `import mime` is not a standard module. So while importing `mime` in your program python raises an exception. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016186/how-to-detect-if-numpy-is-installed for import error and http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/import.html for documentation on python

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following tutorial, from `effbot.org`: [How do I send mail from a Python script?](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-send-mail-from-a-python-script.htm)

> Use the `smtplib` module.
>
> SEND simple email
>
> ```
> import smtplib
>
> SERVER = "localhost"
>
> FROM = "sender@example.com"
> TO = ["user@example.com"] # must be a list
>
> SUBJECT = "Hello!"
>
> TEXT = "This message was sent with Python's smtplib."
>
> # Prepare actual message
>
> message = """\
> From: %s
> To: %s
> Subject: %s
>
> %s
> """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
>
> # Send the mail
>
> server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
> server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
> server.quit()
> ```
>
> Note that the `TO` variable must be a list